# Trouble with strcmp function in C

Tags: c, strcmp

I am writing a function called check that compares the alphabetical string of a dictionary that is loaded in through the command line with a text that is also loaded in through the command line. The function is part of a larger function called speller that acts as a spell checker.

I ran several printf debugging tests to check if the words being compared in the strcmp function. The problem comes here. The function finds that all words in the text are incorrectly spelled even when the printf test shows that the strings from the dictionary and the text are the same.

Don't know where to go from this point so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much
Below is the code for the particular function. Thanks again.

```
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *hashtable[27];

/* Returns true if word is in dictionary else false. */
int hash_fun (const char key);
bool check (const char *word)
{
    //case-desensitizing
    char caseless[strlen (word)];
    int i, length;
    for (int head = 0; head < 26; head++) {
        hashtable[head] = NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0, length = strlen (word); i < length; i++) {
        //("%c\n",word[i]);
        if (isupper (word[i])) {
            caseless[i] = tolower (word[i]);
        } else {
            caseless[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    caseless[i] = '\0';
    //printf("-%s  %s-  \n*",word, caseless);
    int word_index = hash_fun (caseless);

    //printf("%i", word_index);

    node *new_node = malloc (sizeof (node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (word_index >= 0) {
        if (hashtable[word_index] == NULL) {
            hashtable[word_index] = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }

        node *cursor = malloc (sizeof (node));
        cursor = hashtable[word_index];

        while (cursor != NULL) {
            //printf("Dictionary:%s and  Text:%s \n", cursor->word, caseless);
            int found;
            found = strcmp (caseless, cursor->word);

            if (found == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't want `caseless[strlen(word) + 1];`??

Comment: Can you please clean up the code a bit? It got broken up a few lines form the beginning.

Comment: Also, I don't think  you need to allocate memory to cursor to traverse the list.  node* cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));

Comment: Also, `        if (isupper (word[i])) {
            caseless[i] = tolower (word[i]);
        } else {
            caseless[i] = word[i];
        }` is pointless; `tolower` will leave uncased characters unmodified, so you could avoid special cases by unconditionally doing `caseless[i] = tolower(word[i]);`.

Comment: strcmp(one,two) returns -1 if one before two in dictionary order, +1 if one after two, and zero if one and two are the same.

Comment: You haven't shown the code for the "speller" function, so how can we help you find the problem. From your question, I am assuming that the "speller" function is the one the reports all words as incorrectly spelt. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the posted code is missing the #include statements.  Are we expected to guess which header files are included?   The posted code is missing the #define for LENGTH.  The function `tolower()` returns an `int` not a char so this line: `caseless[i] = tolower (word[i]);` should be: `caseless[i] = (char)tolower (word[i]);`

Comment: this line: `int word_index = hash_fun (caseless);` makes integer from pointer.  `(caseless` is an array and in C, referencing an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.) Probably not what you want to do.   Strongly suggest when compiling, to always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the call to `hash_fun()` is being passed a `char *` but is expecting a `char`.  Probably not what you want to do.

Comment: the posted code fails to read in the dictionary.   Suggest, for now, forget about using a hashtable, *which the code is failing to implement) and concentrate of input of the dictionary into a linked list Then, when that is working, then concentrate on checking if the 'word' is in the linked list of dictionary words

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for the feedback. I actually have another function that is part of the spell check function that loads in the dictionary. I didn't post it here because I thought the problem lied in the check function, but if you think it would help I can post that too. Thanks again